# Looking for a formula checking the values of two columns and returning a value

Tags: excel, text, compare, match

I checked throughout the site and didn't see anything exactly matching what I'm looking for.

I have a set of values in Column A and Column B

I want Column C to report text string Z IF the values in Column A match text string X and Column B matches text string Y.

Here's an example.

```
Col A   Col B   Col C
Apple   Banana  Not a Match
Apple   Banana  Not a Match
Apple   Banana  Not a Match
Apple   Banana  Not a Match
Apple   Strawberry  Match
Apple   Strawberry  Match
Apple   Strawberry  Match
Orange  Banana  Not a Match
Orange  Banana  Not a Match
Orange  Banana  Not a Match
Orange  Grapefruit  Not a Match
Orange  Grapefruit  Not a Match
Orange  Grapefruit  Not a Match
```

I want to be able to have the 3rd column automatically report a text string (that I will specify) in column C ONLY if Column A AND Column B matches the values I enter. In this example, a match is reported ONLY if Column A = Apple AND Column B = Strawberry.

Is this something that can easily be done?

Comment: you can use an IF statement `=IF(AND(A2="Apple",B2="Strawberry"),"Match","Not a Match")`

Comment: okay, I'll give that a shot. Was trying IF > Lookup > AND > Lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the formula that you need:

`=IF (AND(A1="a";B1="b");"match";"not match")`

And here is a good reference for IF AND in excel:
http://www.experiglot.com/2006/12/11/how-to-use-nested-if-statements-in-excel-with-and-or-not/

Comment: OP might need to change `;` to `,` depending on their local settings